# How do I use $ holders to capitalize the first letter of each sentence in a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have string like this:

```
      THiS is a Li?ne of text  
   !THiS is a Line of text    
((THiS is a Line of text.X    
    THiS is a Line of text
```

I want to capitalize each line but keep it in its original form.

So far I have:

```
puts the_string.gsub(/(^\W*?)([a-z])/) { |x| "#{$2.capitalize}"}
```

but this gets rid of the whitespace.

Comment: In this case, `"{$2.capitalize}"` and `$2.capitalize` are the same thing. The quotes aren't required.

Comment: Please give examples of the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but this may help:

```
puts the_string.gsub(/(^\W*?)([a-z])/) { |x| "#{$1}#{$2.capitalize}"}
```

This also puts the first captured group (i.e. the spaces) back into the result string.

Comment: The non-greedy operator `?` is redundant. `\W` will not extend into `[a-z]` because they are exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You're not dealing with the rest of the word:

```
lines = [
  " THiS is a Li?ne of text",
  "!THiS is a Line of text",
  "((THiS is a Line of text.X",
  "THiS is a Line of text"
]

lines.each do |line|
  puts line.gsub(/(\w+)/) { $1.capitalize }
end

# =>  This Is A Li?Ne Of Text  
# => !This Is A Line Of Text    
# => ((This Is A Line Of Text.X    
# => This Is A Line Of Text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = <<_
      THiS is a Li?ne of text  
   !THiS is a Line of text    
((THiS is a Line of text.X    
    THiS is a Line of text  
_

string.gsub(/\w.*/, &:capitalize)
# =>
#      This is a li?ne of text  
#   !This is a line of text    
#((This is a line of text.x    
#    This is a line of text
```